# Gradle Kotlin DSL: could not find or load main class

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build

I have a Java project with multiple dependencies that I would like to package into a fat jar with Gradle using Kotlin DSL.

When I run `./gradlew jar`, the build succeeds, but it cannot find the main class when I try to run it:

```
$ ./gradlew jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed

$ java -jar build/libs/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class mypackage.Hello
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.Hello

$ jar xf build/libs/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
$ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: mypackage.Hello

$ jar -tf build/libs/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep mypackage                                                          1
mypackage/
mypackage/Hello.class
```

Here is the full `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
group = "myapp"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    withSourcesJar()
}

plugins {
    java
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.12.0")
}

val mainClassName = "mypackage.Hello"
tasks.jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
    manifest.attributes.apply {
        put("Class-Path", configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().asPath)
        put("Main-Class", mainClassName)
    }

    from(configurations.compileClasspath.get().map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) })
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And a link to my repo: https://github.com/darkasphalt/myapp

Comment: How does the `Hello` class look? Does it have a compatible `main` function?

Comment: @Joffrey yes it does. It just prints out "Hello": https://github.com/darkasphalt/myapp/blob/master/src/main/java/mypackage/Hello.java

Answer (score 1):

Check the content of jar. The problem is, that you include all the contents of the the libs. This also also adds files from the java module system like the `module-info.class`. This may hide your Main class.

#### Simple Fix

Your main works, if you:

a) Remove the import
`implementation("com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.12.0")`
**or**
b) Remove the classpath config:
`from(configurations.compileClasspath.get().map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) })`

Than a simple `java -jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` will print out the:

> Hello

#### Setup with ShadowJar

To solve the problem of packaging a fat jar the right way, you might use the [ShadowJar](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin. With this setup, the bundled jar works:

```kotlin
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

group = "myapp"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

plugins {
    java
    application
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow").version("7.0.0")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    withSourcesJar()
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage")
    }
}

application() {
    mainClass.set("mypackage.Hello")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.12.0")
}

// Configure Shadow to output with normal jar file name:
tasks.named<ShadowJar>("shadowJar").configure {
    minimize()
}

tasks {
    build {
        dependsOn(shadowJar)
    }
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: You actually helped narrow down the exact issue I was having which seems to be related to log4j dependencies.  
  
a. Removing the import is not an option. I used the azure dependency as an example. My app has a lot of other dependencies, but it seems like the main issue is when I try to import log4j dependencies.  
  
b. I've seen this classpath config across various Gradle posts regarding compiling fat jars. I have even used the same exact line across other projects that have compiled and ran successfully. Seems something has changed with Gradle 7+.

Comment: If this is an option for you, check out the [ShadowJar](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) build plugin. I updated my answer with a working version of your build script.